# Library error with Eclipse for c/c++ on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, matrix

I have been working with the build-essential package for c/c++ buildings in Ubuntu Oneric (updates up to date).

I want to use the Indigo C++ Eclipse for Linux 32 bits. I decompressed the file "eclipse-cpp-indigo-SR1-incubation-linux-gtk.tar.gz" on my desktop and I runned the file Eclipse.exe, the Eclipse UI works fine.

The problem appears when I tried to compile a simple HelloWorld.cpp program:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main() {
      printf("!!!Hello World!!!");
      return 0;
 }
```

The stdio.h library and the printf function could not be resolved. So I tried to enter the library manually using this steps:

1. On Menu: Project->Properties->C/C++ General->Paths and Symbols
2. I selected the Include tab with the GNU C++ language
3. I have the possibility of choose a system variable and a system folder.

I have no idea where are located the C/C++ libraries, I tried unsuccesfully with:

1. usr/include/c++/4.6
2. usr/share/build-essential
3. ${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
4. ${CDTVersion}

Thanks in advance.

---

By the way, do you know some GUI Designer that works for C/C++ in Eclipse with Linux?

Answer (score 2):

I've never personally programmed in C using Linux, however it sounds like stdhio.h is completely non existent on your system. A quick google search led me [here](http://www.spiration.co.uk/post/1291/ubuntu%3a-error%3a-stdio.h%3a-No-such-file-or-directory). You may need to install a required development package, try:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Comment: Thanks KillAWatt1705, but I have installed already that package.

Answer (score 1):

The libraries in Ubuntu (and I think most of the *nix-like systems) are located in **/usr/lib**, while the header files are located in **/usr/include**

Comment: Excellent Narrakan, it works! By the way, do you know some GUI Designer that works for C/C++ in Eclipse with Linux?

Comment: @juanma2268 sorry, I don't. I mostly use Qt for GUI design, being free and cross-platform.